# Full width button w/ flex-box in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox and am unable to produce a full width button in react-native. I've been trying to figure this out myself for over a day and have read every related article / post on the internet to no avail.

I would like to have two `TextInput` elements that span the entire width of the screen, with a button below them that also spans the full width of the screen. The `TextInput` elements *are* spanning the full width of the screen, but this appears to be by default in the Android simulator I'm running.

Here's my code:

```js
 var MyModule = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headline}>
                <Text>Hello World</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
                <TextInput style={[styles.input]} placeholder="Email" />
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    style={[styles.input]}
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={styles.fullWidthButton}
                    onPress={this.buttonPressed}
                >
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
},
buttonPressed: function() {
    console.log("button was pressed!");
}
});

var paddingLeft = 15;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
inputsContainer: {
    // Intentionally blank because I've tried everything & I'm clueless
},
fullWidthButton: {
    // Intentionally blank because I've tried everything & I'm clueless
},
input: {
    paddingLeft: paddingLeft,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white"
},
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
    alignItems: "stretch"
},
headline: {}
});

module.exports = Onboarding;
```

Anyone know what I need to do to get the `TouchableHighlight` to span the full width of the screen?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I came here looking for the same question. Having experimented further, I've found the simplest way is to use `alignSelf: 'stretch'`. This forces the individual element to take up the full width available e.g.

```
 button: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
 }
```

Nader's answer does work of course, but this would seem to be the correct way using Flexbox.

Comment: on <Button> alignSelf:'stretch' does not work, It works on Touchables though

Comment: @Pankaj, it would only work for me on a `<Button>` if you wrap it with a View with flex: 1.

`<View style={{ flex: 1 }}><Button style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
    </View>`

Answer (score 30):

You can achieve this by setting a flex:1 property on the parent element of the TouchableHighlight, then assigning a flexDirection:row property to the TouchableHighlight element:

```js
<View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.fullWidthButton} onPress={this.buttonPressed}>
        <Text style={styles.fullWidthButtonText}>Submit</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>

  inputsContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  fullWidthButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height:70,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  fullWidthButtonText: {
    fontSize:24,
    color: 'white'
  }
```

I've set up a full working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/J6fnqg). Also, the full code is below.

https://rnplay.org/apps/J6fnqg

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
} = React;

var MyModule = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.headline}>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>

        <TextInput style={[styles.input]} placeholder="Email" />
        <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} style={[styles.input]} placeholder="Password" />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.fullWidthButton} onPress={this.buttonPressed}>
          <Text style={styles.fullWidthButtonText}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    </View>
  },
  buttonPressed: function() {
    console.log('button was pressed!');
  }
});

var paddingLeft = 15;


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputsContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  fullWidthButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    height:70,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  fullWidthButtonText: {
    fontSize:24,
    color: 'white'
  },
  input: {
    paddingLeft: paddingLeft,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  headline: {
  }
});



AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyModule', () => MyModule);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with react-native 0.15.0 running in Android 6.0 (and the Android simulator is broken in the playground you provided). I copy pasted your exact file, and the button displays as it was before (it's merely the width of its text). Is this a React bug?

Comment: Maybe try this:

var windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

 <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.fullWidthButton, {width: windowWidth} ]} >

Also, updated the example to implement this.

Comment: alignItems: 'stretch' on the container was the missing key for me just in case someone made the suggested changes and is still having a problem.

Answer (score 13):

The provided solution didn't work for me. You have to wrap the Buttons in an additional `View` component:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
        <Button title="Button 1" />
    </View>
    <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
       <Button title="Button 2" />
    </View>
</View>
```

Or use the `Text` component along with `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style = {{width: "50%"}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}} > Button 1 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style = {{width: "50%"}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}} > Button 1 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Try out both solutions here: https://snack.expo.io/wAENhUQrp

- `justifyContent: 'space-between'` doesn't use all available space for the buttons
- `button {alignSelf: 'stretch'}` doesn't work on the Button component

Answer (score 4):

Now there is a predefined component Button. Even if you use text, you need to pay attention to the View width:

```
<View style={[{width:"100%"}]}>
    <Button
        onPress={this.closeModal}
        title="Close"
        color="#841584"
        style={[{borderRadius: 5,}]}
        hardwareAccelerated
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets use the below source that helps to set width and height of button. Here you need to specify the button width and height parameter in view layout.

```
<View style={[{ width: "90%", margin: 10, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
   <Button
      onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
      title="Button Three"
      color="#90A4AE"
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
alignItems: 'center',
width: '100%',
```

example:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <Button style={styles.button} />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
})
```