# How to center form elements in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating login form in react-native I want to put login form in center. Though form is coming in center but button is not taking full width and margin as TextInput.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Below is my code:

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Button,Text, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Login = ({navigation}) => {

 return(
    <View style={styles.loginBox}>
        
        <Text style={styles.login}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username"/>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password"/>    
        <Button style={styles.butStyle} title="LOGIN"/>
    
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 loginBox:{
     flex:1,
     alignItems:'center',
     justifyContent:'center'
 },
 login:{
   fontWeight:'bold',
   fontSize:20
 }, 
 input:{
     borderRadius:5,
     borderColor: "#adadad",
     borderWidth:2,
     marginTop:15,
     marginLeft:15,
     marginRight:15,
     paddingLeft:15,
     alignSelf: 'stretch'
 },
 butStyle:{
     borderRadius:5,
     marginTop:10,
     margin:15,
 }   
});

export default Login;
```

What needs to be corrected in the above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full width button w/ flex-box in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011508/full-width-button-w-flex-box-in-react-native)

Comment: I have already been through this post but `alignSelf: 'stretch'` property is not working for button style.

Comment: Did you try wrapping inside another `View` with `flex:1` like mentioned in comments.?  I know you have it inside a view, but it's also got justifyContent & alignItems and I'm just wondering if it's overriding the alignSelf.   I don't use React Native personally, so I've not checked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you can use TouchableOpacity

```js
    <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:"blue", alignSelf:"stretch", marginHorizontal:15, padding:15, marginTop:15 , justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", borderRadius: 5}}>
          <Text style={{color:"white" , fontWeight:"bold"}}>Login</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Can you please tell how can I make form stable because when keyboard opens it moves up.

Comment: <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" style={styles.loginBox}>
<Text style={styles.login}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username"/>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password"/>    
        <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:"blue", alignSelf:"stretch", marginHorizontal:15, padding:15, marginTop:15 , justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", borderRadius: 5}}>
          <Text style={{color:"white" , fontWeight:"bold"}}>Login</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>    
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

Comment: Do i need to wrap from elements inside `<KeyboardAvoidingView> </KeyboardAvoidingView>`

Comment: I tried `KeyboardAvoidingView` it is not working.

Comment: I have just added this line ` android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest file and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using latest react-native>=0.63, you can use a new [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component.

```
<Pressable onPress={onPressFunction}>
  <Text>Login</Text>
</Pressable>
```